# Password Generator not working OS X

Tags: bash, osx, random

I am creating a Password Generator using 4 Arrays (Lower Case, Upper Case, Symbol and Number) with the RANDOM function. Basically I will generate a random number and then apply it to each of those arrays.

**Here is my script.**

```
LOWER[0]="a"
LOWER[1]="b"
LOWER[2]="c"
LOWER[3]="d"
LOWER[4]="e"
LOWER[5]="f"
LOWER[6]="g"
LOWER[7]="h"
LOWER[8]="i"
LOWER[9]="j"
LOWER[10]="k"
LOWER[11]="l"
LOWER[12]="m"
LOWER[13]="n"
LOWER[14]="o"
LOWER[15]="p"
LOWER[16]="q"
LOWER[17]="r"
LOWER[18]="s"
LOWER[19]="t"
LOWER[20]="u"
LOWER[21]="v"
LOWER[22]="w"
LOWER[23]="x"
LOWER[24]="y"
LOWER[25]="z"

UPPER[0]="A"
UPPER[1]="B"
UPPER[2]="C"
UPPER[3]="D"
UPPER[4]="E"
UPPER[5]="F"
UPPER[6]="G"
UPPER[7]="H"
UPPER[8]="I"
UPPER[9]="J"
UPPER[10]="K"
UPPER[11]="L"
UPPER[12]="M"
UPPER[13]="N"
UPPER[14]="O"
UPPER[15]="P"
UPPER[16]="Q"
UPPER[17]="R"
UPPER[18]="S"
UPPER[19]="T"
UPPER[20]="U"
UPPER[21]="V"
UPPER[22]="W"
UPPER[23]="X"
UPPER[24]="Y"
UPPER[25]="Z"

SYMBOL[0]="!"
SYMBOL[1]="@"
SYMBOL[2]="#"
SYMBOL[3]="$"
SYMBOL[4]="%"
SYMBOL[5]="^"
SYMBOL[6]="&"
SYMBOL[7]="*"
SYMBOL[8]="("
SYMBOL[9]=")"

NUMBER[0]="1"
NUMBER[1]="2"
NUMBER[2]="3"
NUMBER[3]="4"
NUMBER[4]="5"
NUMBER[5]="6"
NUMBER[6]="7"
NUMBER[7]="8"
NUMBER[8]="9"
NUMBER[9]="0"

for i in {1..5}; do
  for j in {1..3}; do
    let RANDLOWER=$RANDOM%26
    let RANDUPPER=$RANDOM%26   
    let RANDSYMBOL=$RANDOM%10
    let RANDNUMBER=$RANDOM%10

    echo -n ${LOWER[$RANDLOWER]}
    echo -n ${UPPER[$RANDUPPER]}
    echo -n ${SYMBOL[$RANDSYMBOL]}
    echo -n ${NUMBER[$RANDNUMBER]}

  done >> passwords.txt
echo >> passwords.txt
done
```

However, when it generates  and outputs to the `passwords.txt` it will show a list of all directories of where the script is running.

For example, I am running this script in the `~` directory and it will display all the directories.

**passwords.txt output**

```
bRApplications Desktop Documents Downloads Library Movies Music Pictures Public passwords.txt9vN$3qC(1
sB$1tH#3uV&6
tK#3hK#2bE!
sM^4cP%5sC^3
sB&6lG)6lJ!6
```

**Expected output**

```
sC@1zH&6wO$2
sQ@0vC@2hT%1
rL&7kY%5gY#1
wI#9hC&3oA&4
cZ%6uA!6xM(3
```

What am I missing in this script, why is it giving me this output?

Comment: Not an answer to the question but - why such a complicated method? What's wrong with `tr -cd '[:graph:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w12 | head -n5` to generate random all chars passwords? If you want a more specific char set, instead of [:graph:] you might use `!@#$%^&*()A-Z-a-z-0-9` as your `tr` set.

Comment: Hi @Pandya, it is strange that it will generate some of the passwords fine, however it will then display the directories of where the script is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of your problem by making the following edit to your script:

```
echo -n ${LOWER[$RANDLOWER]}${UPPER[$RANDUPPER]}${SYMBOL[$RANDSYMBOL]}${NUMBER[$RANDNUMBER]}

done >> passwords.txt
echo >> passwords.txt
done
```

For me, it is giving sample output as expected:

```
$ cat passwords.txt 
dI)9oF*5mG(1
pO&9rL%7cO^9
vB#8zF^4uN)3
hW(5dA%0sT^4
iQ*2hG*2gV!7
```

Comment: Hi @Pandya, it is giving me the following output. These are on separate lines

sG&6
kY#2
fP@6

lJ)5
mA*6
rR@2

gV)3
hN%2
jW@6

tZ#3
rV!3
xZ^7

wJ)9
uU)0
nK$6

Comment: @RyanHawdon I've revised the answer, now is it working?

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!! I have marked your post as the answer, however I can't up vote it  since I don't have 15 reputation, sorry. Thanks again :)